# counting a word in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Hi I am a beginner in excel so please bear with my easy questions.
I want to count a word in a range. I can count a word in a cell with the following formulae:

```
=(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"dog","")))/LEN("dog")
```

But when I change the A1 to A1:B1, doesn't like it?

```
=(LEN(A1:B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:B1,"dog","")))/LEN("dog")
```

My table:

A1   dog,cat,dog,cat,dog,dog
B1   dog

Thank you

From

A beginner

Comment: Try to put a screenshot in the question for the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole thing in a SUMPRODUCT in order to count over a range of cells.

eg

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A1:B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:B1,"dog","")))/LEN("dog"))
```

Comment: Thank you, got it.

Answer (score 0):

The method you are trying should be `Array Formula`

`=SUM((LEN(A1:A4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"dog","")))/LEN("dog"))`

Type Ctrl+Shift+Enter to complete the formula.

Comment: I have text in A1,B1  so should the range be A1:B1  when I did Ctrl+Shift+Enter its given me 4 should be 5 counts of word "dog"